# form data with paypal button submission in wordpress website

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, paypal

I have created a button in paypal. When I click the button I need my form data also to be submitted with paypal with validation.

Already i tried some method,
I have created a form with validation. When I click on the button I pass this value to paypal form using jquery and I submit the form there. This submission is working, but mostly it says that "sorry the payment cannot be processed".

My form code is,

```
 <form method="post" id="buy" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" class="paypal-button" target="_top">
 <div class="hide" id="errorBox"></div>
 <input type="hidden" name="button" value="buynow">
 <input type="text" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $_GET['item_name'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_GET['amount'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="return" value="<?php echo $_GET['success_url'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $_GET['failure_url'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="env" value="www.sandbox">
 <input type="text" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $_GET['notify_url'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $_GET['currency'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="os0" value="<?php echo $_GET['your_name'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="os1" value="<?php echo $_GET['youremail'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="on0" value="<?php echo $_GET['date'].'-'.$_GET['month'].'-'.$_GET['year'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="on1" value="<?php echo $_GET['phone'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="on2" value="<?php echo $_GET['sender_email'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
 <input type="text" name="business" value="<?php echo $_GET['paypal_mail'];?>">
 <input type="text" name="bn" value="JavaScriptButton_buynow">
 <button type="hidden" style="display:none" class="paypal-button large">Buy Now</button>
 </form>
```

Get form data by url and submit using script.

Comment: please write your form html and code used to submit form.

Comment: updated the form coding above.

Comment: are you testing it on sandbox or on the live account?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in the form parameters so that's why it is not processing the payments. Please try the following form configurations:

For sandbox accounts always use:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" class="paypal_form">
```

And here is full form html:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" class="paypal_form">
                                <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" />
                                <input name="business" type="hidden" value="yourbussines@mail.com" />
                                <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="IE" />
                                <input name="item_name" id="paypal_name" type="hidden" value="" />
                                <input name="amount" id="paypal_amount" type="hidden" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="last_user_id" value=""/>
                                <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="Your currency code" />
                                <input name="button_subtype" type="hidden" value="products" />
                                <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='your notify url'>
                                <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='your cancel return url'>
                                <input type='hidden' name='return' value='thank you page url'>
                                <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="0" />
                                <input name="add" type="hidden" value="1" />
                                <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
                                <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" type="image" />
                                <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

This will work for you.

Thanks